# The correct way to use Gauss law to calculate an electric field (electrostatics)

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

While studying electrodynamics on my own I stumble with a problem involving the electric field inside a charged spherical shell. I understand that the electric field inside equals zero but I don't understand why many people use Gauss law to prove it.
As I understand Gauss law you can calculate the electric field **inside** of a closed surface but not the electric field outside (since the flux will be zero) and yet the usual proof I found is putting a spherical surface (shell) inside the charged spherical shell, then saying that there is no charge inside the surface and thus the electric field inside the **charged shell** equals zero.
I know I'm misunderstanding something with Gauss law or even something more fundamental but I simply can't get out of this misunderstanding on my own.

Comment: If there are no charges inside, the net flux will be 0. That does not mean that $\vec{E}$ is 0, neccesarily, but, if the flux is 0 **for any surface**, regardless of its size and shape... then it is probably because $\vec{E}=\vec{0}$.

Comment: May I suggest you check out the numerous posts on Gauss’ law on this site.  The tag is a good place to start.  I don’t see how you can’t use G’s law to compute the field outside a closed surface either.